# transferring data from nodejs to shell (expect)

Tags: node.js, shell, expect, args

i have small problem with sending data from nodejs to expect.
i have a shell(expect script), and nodejs script.here it is.

```
var sys = require('sys');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cons = spawn('./some_shell_script', argv=[arqs...]
```

arguments is declared one by one in that way `["arg1":"value1", "arg2":"value2"]`.

and here is my some_shell_script:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect
spawn -noecho o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@111.111.111.111 {*}$arg
```

the problem is that. ssh deleting all quotes and it is necessary to get this args in quotes to in ssh request
is there another way to transfer data from nodejs to expect, or how can i make escaping quotes without doing like this \\?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments must be an array not key-value pairs. The script you are calling must have the logic to decode the arguments. For e.g.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

//calls ls -lh /usr which decodes the options itself
```

You can call the process directly passing the arguments, and extract the arguments from your script itself, like

```
spawn('script', ['opt1', 'opt2']);
```

Inside script you can access the arguments using $n notation like this :

```
$0 #zeroth argument ='script'
$1 #first argument ='opt1'
$2 #second argument ='opt2'
$@ #array of all arguments
```

Comment: i need to send argument with quotes like "arg1"

Comment: You should then escape the quotes with arguments `"\"opt1\""`. Or use different quotes `['"opt1"', '"opt2"']`

Comment: it s not a way to solve the situation, to escape all quotes. there are a lot of argumnts, and escaping all of them - bad idea. can you advice me another way of trnsferring whole "input" line from nodejs to expect?